# Vector Q-Space of Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If V is a vector $\mathbb{Q}$-space of all polynomials with rational coefficients in one variable whose degree $\le 2$, show that $f_1 = 5, \: f_2=3+5x, \: f_3=2-x^2$ form a basis of V.

So we need to show that these are linearly independent and generate V, i.e., we need to show $c_1(5) + c_2(3+5x) + c_3(2-x^2) = 0$.

How do I proceed from here?

I also want to show that $g(x)=2x^2-10x+3$ can be written as a combination of these basis vectors.

Comment: don't you mean *form a basis over $\mathbb Q$*? and they should generate $V$, not $\mathbb R$, in any case..

Comment: yes, it is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to finishing the problem.  This is good:
$$
c_1(5)+c_2(3+5x)+c_3(2-x^2)=0
$$
But remember, you are are equating vectors, which in this case are polynomials. So the right hand side is not the number $0$; it is the constant polynomial $0$.  In other words, the RHS is:
$$0x^2+0x+0.$$
If you expand the LHS and equate coefficients, it should be obvious that all the $c_i$s are zero.

So, this proves that $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is linearly independent.  Since the dimension of $V$ is 3, it follows directly that $g\in V$ can be written as a unique linear combination of $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$.

Or do you need to actually *find* $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ such that 
$$
g=\sum_{1}^{3}\lambda_{i}f_{i}$$
In that case, just expand the following and equate coefficients.  You will end up with (no surprise here) a system of three linear equations in the three unknowns $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$:
$$g(x)=\lambda_1 f_1(x)+\lambda_2 f_2(x) + \lambda_3 f_3(x)
$$

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! I had forgotten to just equate the coefficients. So in the second part I set up $g(x) = 2x^2-10x+3=\lambda_1f_1+\lambda_2f_2+\lambda_3f_3$ and got $\lambda_1=\dfrac{13}{5}, \: \lambda_2=\lambda_3=-2$. But the only question I still have is showing that these vectors generate/span V?

Comment: Also, if I have a linear transformation $\phi: V \rightarrow V$, such that $\phi(h) = (x+3)h'$ for all $h \in V$ where $h=h(x)$, how do I show the matrix $A_\phi$ representing $\phi$ in respect to the basis? I think that it is in essence $\big[\phi(f_1) \: \phi(f_2) \: \phi(f_3) \big]$, where $f_n$ can be written as a vector of coefficients such as $f_1 = \big( \begin{smallmatrix} 5\\ 0\\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \big), \: f_2 = \big( \begin{smallmatrix} 3\\ 5\\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \big), \: f_3 = \big( \begin{smallmatrix} 2\\ 0\\ -1 \end{smallmatrix} \big)$. But then how is $\phi(f_1)$ computed?

Comment: $V$ is a three dimensional space (as witnessed by the trivial fact that $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is a basis).  $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$ containing $3$ elements.  Therefore $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is a basis!

Comment: In answer to your other question, or as a more constructive approach to the basis argument, try expressing the elements of the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ (or $\{\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\ldots\}$, in the more general case) in terms of the new basis. What you are constructing is a *change of basis* transformation.

Comment: Here's a simple example. Let $\{\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2\}$ be a basis for some 2 dimensional space $V$ and let $\{\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2\}$ be another basis, with $$\mathbf{u}_i=\sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_{i,j}\mathbf{e}_j$$ and $$\mathbf{e}_i=\sum_{j=1}^k\mu_{i,j}\mathbf{u}_j.$$ Then the matrix $\Lambda=\pmatrix{\lambda_{1,1}&\lambda_{2,1}\\ \lambda_{1,2}&\lambda_{2,2}}$ has the property that if
$$\Lambda\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{a\\b}$$ then
$$x\mathbf{u}_1+y\mathbf{u}_2=a\mathbf{e}_1+b\mathbf{e}_2.$$
Likewise, $M=\Lambda^{-1}$ is the matrix of the $\mu$s and allows the reverse change of basis.